# Magento email template location?

Tags: templates, email, magento, location

I've been trying to send an email from my magento module but for some reason I can't get the template to work:

The template is set as follows:

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('application_status_email');
```

The headers and all are being sent correctly.

I've created a file called **application_status_email.html** in **app/locale/en_US/template/email** and the selected language on the admin panel is English(US). Thoughts?

The template itself simply contains:

```
<div>
Message:
{{var message}}
</div>
```

But for some reason my emails are sent without anything content. I have another module sending emails, but from the front end wich works fine, with the template located in the same folder ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember to add your email template to the configuration files:

```
<global>
  <template>
    <email>                                                                   
      <application_status_email>
        <label>Application Status Message</label>
        <file>application_status_email.html</file>
        <type>html</type>
      </application_status_email>
    </email>
  </template>
</global>
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Ugh, off course, I'm still not used to working woth Magento's xml files. Thank you.